# Printing a javascript object with space inbetween the variable

Tags: javascript

I have a below JS object and I want to use the values within the object...When I print dataRow.unitsOrdered, I dont have any problem but when I use dataRow.To Zip Code, it throws me a error...How can I fix it?

JS Object

```
dataRow = {
    "unitsOrdered": "1",
    "Bureau": "",
    "To Zip Code": "OTHER, UNDEFINED",
    "Description": "OFFICE SUPPLIES"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use bracket notation as spaces and certain special characters are not allowed when using dot notation.

```
dataRow['To Zip Code']
```

and spaces in keys are generally not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's because it can't parse the JavaScript you've typed, a white space is normally used by the parser to separate expressions. Try using property accessors like this instead and you shouldn't have a problem

```
dataRow["To Zip Code"]
```